# Getting project in custom build task in imported .targets

Tags: .net, msbuild, msbuild-task, msbuild-target

While creating a NuGet package for a custom build task I was wanting to use a separate `.targets` file in the `/build/` folder of the NuGet package.

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <UsingTask TaskName="MyTask" AssemblyFile="..\tools\MyTask.dll" />
    <Target Name="MyTarget">
        <MyTask />
    </Target>
</Project>
```

To have NuGet automatically import the `.targets` file as described under "Import MSBuild targets and props files into project" [here](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/creating-and-publishing-a-package).

Now to my problem. My [`Task`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.build.utilities.task%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) gets the path of the project file being built using[`ProjectFileOfTaskNode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.build.framework.ibuildengine.projectfileoftasknode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx%20%22this.BuildEngine.ProjectFileOfTask). But when the task is declared in an imported `.targets` file, the path of the `.targets` file is returned.

**Is there a way to get at the path of the project file that imported the `.targets` file?**

Looked as if there possibly was a way to get at the information through some non-public fields on `Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskHost` using reflection. But I would rather avoid that if there's a more open way of getting it.

Comment: For debugging you can try running "msbuild project.csproj /pp>projectoutput.log" to preprocess the project.  I'm not certain how this could be done at runtime however :(

Comment: Even if it's possible to use an install script in my NuGet package to somehow enable project preprocessing it wouldn't be desirable. The reason that I want to use the `.targets` file in the first place is so that I don't have to use an install script and thus won't have to have anything in the `./content` or `./lib` folders :)